# avoiding code redundancies for a calculation in Java

Tags: java, redundancy

I have a calculation where i can sum or subtract something but this depends on a simple condition. My problem is, that I don't know how I can change the code, so i don't need to write the calculation twice just with the difference of the + or -. Hopefully somebody can helf me. Thanks in advance.

```
public void changePrice(Stock stock, int amount, boolean isBuying) {
    double roundRandomNumber = Math.round((0.5 + Math.random()) * 100) / 100.00;
    double newPrice;


    //calculates plus or minus depending on the buyoption
    if (isBuying) {
        newPrice = Math.round((stock.getPrice() + roundRandomNumber * 0.1 * amount) * 100) / 100.00;
    } else {
        newPrice = Math.round((stock.getPrice() - roundRandomNumber * 0.1 * amount) * 100) / 100.00;
    }
    if (newPrice > 0 && newPrice < 3000) {
        stock.setPrice(newPrice);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `+1` or `-1` coefficient based on `isBuying` value.

```
newPrice = Math.round((stock.getPrice() + (isBuying ? 1.0 : -1.0) * roundRandomNumber * 0.1 * amount) * 100) / 100.00;
```

Comment: @Lemurumschlag, please accept and/or upvote the answer if it's been helpful -- that's better than "thanks" :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try by extracting just the factor in the condition:

```
public void changePrice(Stock stock, int amount, boolean isBuying) {
    double roundRandomNumber = Math.round((0.5 + Math.random()) * 100) / 100.00;
    double newPrice;


    //calculates plus or minus depending on the buyoption
    double factor;
    if (isBuying) {
        factor = 1.0
    } else {
        factor = -1.0
    }

    newPrice = Math.round((stock.getPrice() + (factor * roundRandomNumber) * 0.1 * amount) * 100) / 100.00;
    if (newPrice > 0 && newPrice < 3000) {
        stock.setPrice(newPrice);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I come up with substitution of `roundRandomNumber` yielding an expression with `( / 100) * 0.1` which can simplified to `* 0.001`.

Also `round(0.5 + x)` can be `ceil(x)`.

Or use `1 + new Random().nextInt(100)`.

```
double roundRandomNumber = Math.ceil((Math.random()) * 100) * 0.001 * amount;
double newPrice = stock.getPrice();
if (isBuying) {
    newPrice += roundRandomNumber;
} else {
    newPrice -= roundRandomNumber;
}
newPrice = Math.round((newPrice * 100) / 100.00; 

if (newPrice > 0 && newPrice < 3000) {
    stock.setPrice(newPrice);
}
```

For the rest it is the reserved register principle: I do stepwise things to `newPrice`.

The boundary condition excludes 0, which is questionable.

Of course `BigDecimal` should be mentioned. The complexity basically stems from wanting fixed point arithmetic with floating point. Unless you need speed, BigDecimal code can be more readable, though verbose.